# RegSetValueEx Only shows writes first character

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

In the following code, RegSetValueEx is only writing the first letter of my string.  I've tried changing the sizes to just about anything I can think of, and I only ever get the first string.  Any help is appreciated.

```
LPCWSTR path = L"Test String";
size_t size = wclsen(path) * sizeof(wchar_t);

DWORD dwResult = RegSetValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                            "SOFTWARE\\My App",
                            0,
                            REG_SZ,
                            (LPBYTE)path,
                            test);
```

I've tried using path.size() * sizeof(wchar_t) and any number of other sizes I could think of, but nothing seems to work right.  Any ideas?

Comment: @chris: Ah you're right, I forgot about that detail.  I saw the cast which raised alarm bells for me and I was perhaps a little too quick on the trigger there.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, I feel the same way when writing the casts :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RegSetValueEx()` expects `REG_SZ` data to be provided as `const TCHAR*`, which in your case is `const CHAR*` per your compiler settings - as evident by the fact that you are able to pass a `char*` to the second parameter, which means you are actually calling `RegSetValueExA()`. Since you are providing a `const WCHAR*` to `RegSetValueExA()`, the first `0x00` byte gets interpreted as a null terminator, hence only a single character value gets written.

Your options are:

1. `RegSetValueExW(..., (const BYTE*) path, ...`
2. `CString sPath(path); RegSetValueEx(..., (const BYTE*) (LPCTSTR) sPath, ...`
3. Switch project settings to Unicode build

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you haven't defined `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE` before compiling, so the zero-byte in your wide string is being interpreted as signaling the end of the string.

Try using `RegSetValueExW` (and `L"SOFTWARE\\My App"`) instead.